# Loading jQuery library from WordPress admin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, jquery, wp-admin

When we are developing Themes, we are taught to enqueue the **jQuery library** if necessary, because no jQuery library is available on the front-end of WordPress (if I'm not wrong). But when we are into the Admin Panel of WordPress, WP is using jQuery for various purposes — WordPress back-end, by core, already loading jQuery into its admin area.

So, when we are developing Back-end features for a Theme or Plugin, and we are in need of loading jQuery, is that possible to load jQuery library from WordPress bundle?

I'm asking this because in one of [my under-dev. plugin](https://github.com/nanodesigns/ad-zonia/blob/master/wp-adzonia.php#L170), I added jQuery library-

- from the jQuery CDN,
- and as a fallback, from the plugin bundle (using [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338806/how-to-check-if-the-web-connection-is-established))

Now, on every page-refresh my admin panel hits the jQuery CDN, and takes the jQuery lib file from the CDN. If there's no internet connection the php-file-read throws a debug error, but the jQuery loads from my plugin bundle.

But if we can load jQuery from the WP bundle, it'll save time and load of a page, I think.

Comment: why can't you use  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );?

Comment: @MortalViews Thanks a lot. That IS the correct answer. Actually I tried that before, but somehow that time it didn't work. Anyways, can you please put that comment as an Answer so that I can mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load jQuery library using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

jQuery library is registered by default, and the handle is 'jquery'.

for more info check:  [Handles and Their Script Paths Registered by WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Handles_and_Their_Script_Paths_Registered_by_WordPress) and the list at the end of [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Note: it is jquery (not jQuery)

code:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
```